# Execute the Script from Mac

Tags: iphone, macos

I am new to mac development. I have to take a iPhone backup by command. There is a site explain about this (http://keepmurmuring.blogspot.com/2009/06/iphone-backup-informationnote.html). I tried to execute the script "System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Resources/AppleMobileDeviceHelper.app/Contents/Resources/AppleMobileBackup" with parameters. But I am not able to access this path and getting error "launch path not accessible". Can anyone help me to access path and complete my task.

```
NSString *_filename =@"System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Resources/AppleMobileDeviceHelper.app/Contents/Resources/AppleMobileBackup";
    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"./ambackup", 
                          @"--backup", @"--target", @"BE1F74EEB98E14D426665D54105DE27821A6C0FE", nil];
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    NSFileHandle *readHandle = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
    NSData *temp = nil;


   NSMutableData *_data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    [task setLaunchPath:_filename];
    [task setArguments:arguments];
    [task setStandardOutput:pipe];
    [task launch];

    while ((temp = [readHandle availableData]) && [temp length]) 
    {
        [_data appendData:temp];
    }


    [task release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Leading Slash in your Filename Path

```
NSString *_filename = @"System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Resources/AppleMobileDeviceHelper.app/Contents/Resources/AppleMobileBackup";
```

Should be:

```
NSString *_filename = @"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Resources/AppleMobileDeviceHelper.app/Contents/Resources/AppleMobileBackup";
```